# Need Trick to Force html code to display on ecommerce site with limited access

Tags: html, e-commerce, customization

I have an eCommerce site where I have limited access to pages via a Site Manager. This gives me access to certain pages and some editable areas of those pages where I can update/modify html code.

I have a payment (https) page that I am trying to modify, (add a couple content statements at the bottom) but I believe the code is being intentionally blocked from displaying on this page.

I have tried to get the software vendor to modify this page for me, but I was told it would change all their customer's pages and they don't want that.

I am wondering if anyone out there would have any ideas or tricks with html code to force show a paragraph and bypass their built-in blocking?

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: What do you mean from "being intentionally blocked from displaying"? Where do you put the code and how it is blocked?

Comment: I have what they call a Dashboard that I login to. There I can select most of the pages on my site, but not all just the ones they allow. I can see one of the payment pages here, but when I add HTML to this page and save it, It is blocked from being displayed live. Other pages such as product pages or home page shows anything I want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you won't be able to do it.
At your eCommerce system, you have a certain Role. That role belongs under some Permission. The Permission is set form your vendor. 
Do you have any Domain or ID?
If yes, you could use JavaScript to manipulate the HTML but create DOM on Window Load.

Comment: domain (http://lowcostprintshop.com) -- not opposed to trying to run JavaScript. not sure if it will allow it or not. If you could point me in the right direct to a particular script, I'd appreciate it. I don't do a whole lot with Java.